# What is the name of the fast organ song in Parasyte -the maxim- ep17 at 6:35?

Tags: music, parasyte

The song is found in episode 17 of Parasyte -the maxim- at 6:35 when a homicidal parasyte says 'one of us has died'.

The song is also found in episode 16 of Parasyte -the maxim- at 10:54 when Migi says 'shit' and Shinichi says 'no way'.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The song you are looking for would be [Full Moon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGy45tGyDCA)

As [Pratyush](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/19592/pratyush-manocha) mentions in the comments, it is available on [special track cd](http://vgmdb.net/album/53967).

Comment: The tune is present in the [Parasyte Special Soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/53967)....